# Apply filter to an element with specific class

Tags: php, wordpress, class, filter

I'm using this filter

```
add_filter( 'render_block', function( $block_content, $block ) {
    if ( 'generateblocks/headline' === $block['blockName'] ) {
        $block_content = str_replace( '<a ', '<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" ', $block_content );
    }

    return $block_content;
}, 10, 2 );
```

But it applies on all blocks `'generateblocks/headline'` that are links.

I would like to know if it's possible to make this filter **only** working for a **specific CSS class**?

Comment: If you are manipulating valid HMTL, you will suffer less disruptions and aggravations if you use a proper DOM parser instead of hacking at the HTML document with simple string manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can add set `Open in new` for a link from the block editor, here is how you could modify the filter after you assign a class to your GB headline:

```
add_filter( 'render_block', function( $block_content, $block ) {
    if ( 'generateblocks/headline' === $block['blockName'] && isset( $block['attrs']['className'] ) && 'my-class' === $block['attrs']['className']  ) {
        $block_content = str_replace( '<a ', '<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" ', $block_content );
    }

    return $block_content;
}, 10, 2 );
```